# Issues customizing Stripe payment form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, token, stripe-payments

Apologies in advance for the long question. I am new to Rails and Stacked Overflow and am running into road blocks.

I have stripe payments working in my app through my payments controller. The `localhost:3000/payments/new` works perfectly, but now I need to expand it in my app reservation app.

Currently when a user finds a table they like at a venue they can make a reservation. I did this by copying over the reservation/new form into a partial in my tables show page for a specific table

tables/show:

```
<%= render :partial=>'new_reservation', :locals=> {:reservation => Reservation.new(:table_id=> @table.id)} %>
```

And the following code for the partial:

```
<%= form_for(reservation) do |f| %>
  <% if reservation.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(reservation.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this reservation from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% reservation.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_id %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :user_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :table_id %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :table_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :reservation_date %><br>
    <%= f.date_field :reservation_date %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now I'd like to add the following code from my payments/new file to this partial to integrate stripe into the new reservation process:

```
<div id="new_card">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.hidden_field :stripe_token %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Card Number</label>
      <input id="card-number" type="text" placeholder="4242 4242 4242 4242" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>CV Code</label>
      <input id="cvc" type="text" placeholder="123" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Expiry Month</label>
      <input id="exp-month" type="text" placeholder="12" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Expiry Year</label>
      <input id="exp-year" type="text" placeholder="14" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :amount %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :amount %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have updated the javascript for my reservation.js to the following:

```
$( function() {
    $('#card-number').reservation'formatCardNumber')
    $('#cvc').reservation('formatCardCVC')
    $('#exp-month, #exp-year').reservation('restrictNumeric')

    $(document).on('click', "#new_reservation [name='commit']", function( event ) {
        if( $('input[name=saved_card]:checked').val() !== 'true' ) {
        event.preventDefault()
            var card = {
                number:   $("#card-number").val(),
                expMonth: $("#exp-month").val(),
                expYear:  $("#exp-year").val(),
                cvc:      $("#cvc").val()
            }

            Stripe.createToken(card, function( status, response ) {
                if (status === 200) {
                    $("[name='reservation[stripe_token]']").val(response.id)
                    $("#new_reservation").submit()
                } else {
                    $("#stripe-error-message").text(response.error.message)
                    $("#credit-card-errors").show()
                    $("#user_submit").attr("disabled", false)
                }
            } )
        }
    } )

    $("[name='saved_card']").change( function() {
        showSaved = $(this).val() === 'true'
        $('#saved_card').toggle( showSaved )
        $('#new_card').toggle( ! showSaved )
    } )
    $("[name='saved_card']").eq(0).prop( 'checked', true ).change()
} )
```

The only issue is these payment do not show up on my stripe dashboard nor does the stripe_token pass to reservations.stripe_token through the hidden field.However, I get no errors and the reservation shows up as complete.

I have loaded the proper js in my application header, and stripe works when I use payments/new. Not sure why when i copy over the code it fails.

Should I attack the problem at another angle?

Comment: I'd strongly advice you to [switch to Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js/switching) for easier [PCI compliance](https://support.stripe.com/questions/do-i-need-to-be-pci-compliant-what-do-i-have-to-do). That said, could you check if `$("[name='reservation[stripe_token]']")` returns any element in a JS console in your browser?

Comment: How would I go about checking that sorry. I'm very new to JS.